# Pushing to Heroku Error: Yarn executable was not detected in the system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to push my Ruby on Rails project to Heroku, but when I run git push heroku master, I get this error:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote: Running: rake assets:precompile
remote: Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote: Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
```

and then a bunch of these errors:

```
I, [2018-03-22T02:21:50.236717 #1447]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_82b4e154630ed085855457
42b1fdeafe/public/assets/Muli-Light-0a7e8666b0b0649d6f0c6608ba44881e33a81f7c8ec703e44d20ba27920a2cd0.eot
```

I've tried reinstalling yarn, updating yarn, reinstalling node, updating node, and when I look for the version of yarn in the terminal, I get this:

```
yarn -v
1.5.1
```

I have also tried `npm install yarn -g` , but that didn't change the error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

So after further looking into the issue, it seems that I need to have node js and ruby buildbpacks, update brew and yarn, run bin/yarn, and also commit any changes. Here is a thread on the issue [github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/739](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/739)
Thanks to @Rob and @davejagoda in the comments.

Comment: I don't have this setup, but is this the answer?: https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/2792

Comment: Thanks for the idea, just added nodejs buildpack to the ruby buildpack, but that didn't fix it. I also added the webpacker gem, but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `heroku buildpacks`?

Comment: 1. heroku/nodejs
   2. heroku/ruby

Comment: So after further looking into the buildpacks, it seems that I had to have node js and ruby buildbpacks, update brew and yarn, run bin/yarn, and also commit any changes. Here is a thread on the issue https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/739

Comment: However, I still have an error regarding Uglifier and precompiling assets failing, but I'll add a new question for that

Comment: are you using webpack in rails?

Answer (score 0):

For me I solved doing:

Add nodejs builpacks with index 1

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

**/.slugignore**

```
yarn.lock <--- Remove this
```